# Identifying the first byte in each block of USART data

Tags: gcc, frame, microcontroller, usart, sequence-alignment

Is there an accepted/effective means for designating/identifying the first byte in each block of a stream of 8 bit data where the blocks update and repeat? I am using GCC. These are control settings data being passed over a USART between two uC, and I need to insure the frame alignment on the receiving side. I can append a header to each instance of the block, but the data can assume any value that the header could have.

Answer (score 2):

Consider [HDLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Level_Data_Link_Control) (see the sections on Framing).